# Why is the output of my pthread and semaphore program blank?

Tags: c, terminal, output, pthreads, semaphore

The following code is written in C, and when I run the code nothing outputs to the screen.  I am not coding in an IDE, so I cannot tell where the error is located.  Please, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


int counter=0;//this is the count variable and is the variable that the treads will edit, making it the critical section
static sem_t semaphore;//this creates a pointer for our semaphore variable

void *increaseCounter();
void *decreaseCounter();

int main()
{

    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 1);

    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, increaseCounter, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, decreaseCounter, NULL);
    
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
}

void *increaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter++;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}

void *decreaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter--;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `pthread_create` to verify threads are correctly created. Also, the thread handler function should be defined to take an `void *` parameter. Finally, performing basic debugging such as putting a print statement at the start of the thread function to see if the thread runs at all.

Comment: One major issue is that `semaphore` is a NULL pointer. Instead should be declared as `static sem_t semahpore;` and passed in as `sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 1);`

Comment: @kaylum I fixed that, but am still receiving absolutely no output

Comment: Fixed what exactly? Did you do the basic debugging as suggested? Did you check the return value of `pthread_create`?

Comment: @kaylum, I also tried putting print statements after each thread creation and after the semaphore creation and it looks as if it never even runs the main() method.  Even with the first statement being a print statement, nothing is outputting

Comment: But did you fix up the semaphore? After I fixed that it works as expected. I also added `#include <pthread.h>` removed the while loop just to shorten the  log): https://ideone.com/oolMVR

Comment: And are you sure your code is actually compiling successfully? It's missing `#include <pthread.h>`.

Comment: @kaylum, I'm sorry for any confusion, let me explain.  I did try the print statements, I included <pthread.h> and I fixed the semaphore's initial declaration and inserted & to all the other locations where it is used.  I am compiling my code with ``` gcc -o xfile file.c -pthread``` and getting nothing output.  Even with a print statement being the initial operation in the main()

Comment: Then there is something else going on. Maybe you are not saving the file or are compiling the wrong file or running the wrong file. Please check all that. For example, put some wrong syntax and check that the build fails, then remove all the code and just have `printf("hello world\n")` in `main` etc.

Comment: @kaylum, I removed the underscore from the initial declaration of the semaphore, saved, compiled, then ran the file.  I got a long list of errors.  Putting the _ back in and recompiling still output nothing

Answer (score 2):

Run but its a loop, might gonna help you

```
gcc -g -Wall -o test NAME.c -lpthread
```

./test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//this is the count variable and is the variable that 
//the treads will edit, making it the critical section
static int counter=0;
//this creates a pointer for our semaphore variable
static sem_t semaphore;

void *increaseCounter();
void *decreaseCounter();

int main()
{
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 1);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, increaseCounter, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, decreaseCounter, NULL);
    
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
}

void *increaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter++;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}

void *decreaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter--;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}
```

Comment: my code looks identical and I compiled it just as you typed with a different file directory of course.  Nothing was output...

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a couple of changes in your code will run fine.

Always read the documentation before writing something. Here I'm attaching some documents that may help u in the future [Synchronizing Threads with POSIX Semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/%7Emdamian/threads/posixsem.html).

This may improve your understanding of threads 
[POSIX thread (pthread) libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

 int counter=0;
 sem_t semaphore;
void *increaseCounter();
void *decreaseCounter();

int main()
{
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 1);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, increaseCounter, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, decreaseCounter, NULL);
    
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
}

void *increaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter++;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}

void *decreaseCounter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter--;
        printf("\n%d\n",counter);
        sem_post(&semaphore);
    }
}
```

Comment: my code looks identical to what you have written, yet mine outputs nothing

Comment: which compiler you are using?

Comment: @ yagami I am using gcc

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Maybe you can try some online GCC compilers and see the output. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: thank you.  I have no idea why it wouldn't work.  I'm running in virtual box, but it's never been a problem before